# How to simulate data with ties in R

Tags: correlation, simulation, ranks, ties

I am using R to investigate the effect of tied values on rank-based correlation statistics

I wish to simulate correlated bivariate standard normal data with some specified proportion of tied values (in, say, X).

Consider the univariate standard normal distribution, One way to generate ties is to round the data. However the fraction of ties increases with the sample size:

```
set.seed(1234)
sum(duplicated(round(rnorm(10), 1))) # returns 1 = 10%
sum(duplicated(round(rnorm(100), 1))) # returns 64 = 64%    
sum(duplicated(round(rnorm(1000), 1))) # returns 942 = 94.2%
```

Note that ‘duplicated()’ determines which elements of a vector or data frame are duplicates of elements with smaller subscripts ... In the first example above there is one pair of tied values (20%).

What I would like to do is simulate data with a specified fraction of tied values. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: The probability of seeing ties in a sample from an absolutely continuous distribution is zero.  Are you sure that's what you want to sample from?

Comment: What one should do very much depends on what, exactly you're trying to find out --"data with ties" is pretty vague/general. The probability of a pair of values being tied relates to the sums of squares of the individual probabilities, which in turn depends very much on the distribution (of course, beyond doubles, there's also triples, etc). Why is rounding normal distributions (in particular) related to the underlying question, moreso than some other choice? Is there something (albeit unstated) about that choice that's related to what you need to know?